# Unable to download a sent file with fastify

Tags: node.js, fastify

## Edit

No solutions worked for me, so I ended up doing the following:

```
// in handler

return reply.sendFile('my_script.sql', 'scripts');
```

```
// on the client
const { data } = await axios({
    url: '/api/generate',
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob'
})

const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'my_script.sql');

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

This works like a charm

---

**Original post**:

I have a simple endpoint as follows:

```js
fastify.get('/generate', async (request, reply) => {
     console.log('endpoint hit'); // this line is printed

     const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'scripts', 'my_script.sql');

     reply.sendFile(filePath, 'scripts');
})
```

This just sends the contents of the `sql` file in text form like so:

[image: img1]

I know that [express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) has a `res.download` method, but I couldn't find an analog with fastify.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I download this file?

Comment: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static#sending-a-file-with-content-disposition-header

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fastify-static`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static/) or by sending the right headers:

```js
fastify.get('/', (request, reply) => {
  const filePath = require('path').join(
    __dirname,
    '../../scripts/my_script.sql'
  )
  const stream = require('fs').createReadStream(filePath)
  reply.header(
    'Content-Disposition',
    'attachment; filename=foo.sql'
  reply.send(stream).type('application/sql').code(200)
})
```

Comment: I was able to set the headers without `fastify-static`. I don't think it's needed.